# Check if an app is installed on an iPhone in iOS9 and up?

Tags: ios9, uiapplication

I need to know if a specific app is installed.

I can't add the Schemes to the plist LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
so the function UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL() is not helpful from iOS9.

Comment: Then you are out of luck, the only document (and therefor allowed way) to check if an app is installed you will have to use the `canOpenURL`, method.